# Date picker in Jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I am stuck trying to get a datepicker to work using Jade. Framework is node.js and express.

I load the javascripts in index.jade like this:

```
link(type='text/css', href='css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css',  rel='stylesheet')
script(src='js/jquery-1.8.2.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='js/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js', type='text/javascript')
```

I have tried several ways of using these javascripts in code beneath, but there must be something I am missing. I found these lines of code on the same spot i found the referance to the jQuery libraries:

```
$(function(){
 $.datepicker.setDefaults(
 $.extend($.datepicker.regional[""])
 );
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

How can I express or use that in Jade?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work as your template (assuming you have the css/js files installed and they can be loaded properly):

```
!!!5
html
  head
    link(type='text/css', href='css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css',  rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='js/jquery-1.8.2.js', type='text/javascript')
    script(src='js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js', type='text/javascript')
    script(src='js/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js', type='text/javascript')
    script
      $(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults(
          $.extend($.datepicker.regional[""])
        );
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
  body
    #datepicker
```

Comment: Thanks mate, with some extra googling and your tips I got it working!